# Signal offset using FRDM-KL25Z

Tags: voltage-divider, voltage-measurement, dc-offset

I am developing a voltmeter using FRDM-KL25Z and I needed a voltage divider with a 1.65V offset, and here is the circuit I am using:

[image]

Does the offset work well? Is there any other (easy) way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Hint: You need to add the offset to both of your Vout lines. This diagram would cause a -1.65 volt DC error on the AC Vout as it is now.

Comment: I have just solved it, thanks. If you want, I can send you the circuit.

Comment: That would be great. Then this Q&A can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final circuit, just a slight change.

[image]

Comment: Great. You have solved your own problem with just a hint. Remember your output is PR2 and Vin AC, both of which have an offset of 1.65 volts. This circuit works as long as Vin AC is floating and has no previous ground ref.